# Delta table merge on multiple columns

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, delta-lake

i have a table which has primary key as multiple columns so I need to perform the merge logic on multiple columns

```
DeltaTable.forPath(spark, "path")
  .as("data")
  .merge(
    finalDf1.as("updates"),
    "data.column1 = updates.column1 AND data.column2 = updates.column2 AND data.column3 = updates.column3 AND data.column4 = updates.column4 AND data.column5 = updates.column5")
  .whenMatched
  .updateAll()
  .whenNotMatched
  .insertAll()
  .execute()
```

When I check the data counts it is not updating as expected.

Could someone help me here on this?

Comment: can you take one of the input rows that should match and you do `select * from table condition_on_all_primary_key` for some of the input rows - do you see them as a new rows? Also, what is the DBR version?

Comment: Hi,

The Duplication is occurring only for 20 to 30 rows.

i.e I'm getting 5320 by the above merging code

But my actual count is 5302 with the unique fields.

Answer (score 0):

Please try also approach like in this example: https://docs.databricks.com/_static/notebooks/merge-in-cdc.html
Create a changes tables with additional columns which you will note

- if a row is new (be inserted)
- old (primary key exists) and nothing has changed
- old (primary key exists) but other fields needs an update
  and then use additional conditions on merge, for example:

```
.whenMatched("s.new = true")
.insert()
.whenMatched("s.updated = true")
.updateExpr(Map("key" -> "s.key", "value" -> "s.newValue"))
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you counting your rows?

One thing to keep in mind is that **directly** reading and counting from the parquet files produced by Delta Lake  will potentially give you a different result than reading the rows through the delta table interface. Remember that delta keeps a log and supports time travel so it does store copies of rows as they change over time.

Here's **a** way to accurately count the current rows in a delta table:

```
deltaTable = DeltaTable.forPath(spark,<path to your delta table>)

deltaTable.toDF().count()
```